# Why redis client does not respond to commands?

Tags: redis

Can someone say whats wrong happens and what can I do?

I install redis by [instruction](https://redis.io/download) in Ubuntu. I run `redis-server` and it show me next screen.

[image]

After that I run `redis-cli` and try to run `PING` command but nothing happens. No error, no message. Whats wrong happens?

Comment: What does redis-cli say? Does it print `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`? What is the output of `netstat -apn | grep 6379`?

Comment: same problem. redis-clis prints nothing. netstat response :
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        1      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7673/redis-server * 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:24982         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 7679/redis-cli      
tcp       14      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:24982         ESTABLISHED -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      7673/redis-server *

Answer (score 0):

Following instructions described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis) solved my problem. Had to run the following command from redis's utils directory

```
sudo ./install_server.sh
```

To start and stop the service

```
sudo service redis_6379 start
sudo service redis_6379 stop
```